# Swift Facebook Login Stopped Working

Tags: facebook, swift, parse-platform, cocoapods

I'm having a very strange problem that I can't find the answer to. I had the parse login working perfectly. I added pods and now my app crashes when I try to log in to facebook. I've isolated the problem to the graph request never opening so the user is always nil. My login that used to work that now stopped looks like this:

```
func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) {

    if ((error) != nil)
    {
        // Process error
    }
    else if result.isCancelled {
        // Handle cancellations

        //move to create account screen
        let secondViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginView") as! LoginViewController
        self.navigationController!.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)

    }
    else {

        println("RESULT: \(result)") **<- Log shows result as "RESULT: <FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult: 0x7f9271d83720>"**

        //Logged in! Let's go to the game
        returnUserData()

        //set the controller
        let secondViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FriendsTableViewController") as! UITableViewController
        //go to the controller
        self.navigationController!.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
    }
}


func returnUserData()
{
    println("98")
    let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: nil)
    println("100")
    graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
    println("102") **<-- NEVER GETS TO THIS**
        if ((error) != nil)
        {....
```

My pods file looks like this:

```
target 'AppName' do
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.0'
pod 'JSQMessagesViewController', '>7.0'
end
```

I removed the Pods and it's still not working? Any insight as to why this could be? Thanks

Comment: The information you have provided is not enough to give you advice. How are you including Parse and Facebook into your project? If you're not using cocoapods, maybe it might be a good idea to integrate them into your project that way and seeing if it changes anything.